# Getting a File off a Linux box using Putty

Tags: windows, linux, file, putty

I was wondering how one would get a file off of a linux server and onto a windows desktop.  Im using putty to connect to the linux box. Thanks

Comment: Use pscp, which should come with the putty distribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `pscp`, included into the normal PuTTY distribution. If you like better GUI, you can use FileZilla, that supports SFTP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pscp for that. It's putty's sibling: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that most Linux servers have FTP servers installed, or are SSH enabled, you could install an FTP client on your Windows desktop, FTP / SFTP to your Linux server, and transfer anything up / down in that fashion.

Here is a [post](http://java.sg/how-to-sftp-from-windows-command-prompt-using-psftp/) detailing how - if you wish to play around with using command prompt and psftp.